# Bash list/process files in a specific order

Tags: linux, bash, redhat-enterprise-linux, bash-scripting

```
#! bash
```

I've tried a few things I've seen on google but nothing seems to work.

I don't see how this should be a high challenge but maybe it just isn't possible?

I have a list of files in a folder names

```
01_one.txt
02_two.txt
03_three.txt
....
```

I need a bash command/script for-each loop that processes the file in the implied sequence (`1, 2, 3, ...`)
as if by hand you might

```
mycmd 01_one.txt
mycmd 02_two.txt
mycmd 03_three.txt
...
```

This is rhel 7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash globbing will return the filenames in *lexical* (i.e. alphabetic) order. As long as the leading digits are zero-padded, this should work:

```
for file in *; do
    mycmd "$file"
done
```

Comment: Like a charm.  And how brilliant someone thought how to make something so routine so easy.